# send all /mod/users URLs to a folder called moderator

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of my project, that contains all the rewrite rules for the site to functions. Most of these rules belong to the `mod` section of the site, and only two of them belong to the front end, which the users use.

Problem is, when a front end user uses the site, apache ends up matching all the rules including the ones for the mods and signup etc, until it reaches the one for the end user, which I feel is unnecessary. I've checked this in the `.htaccess` log.

How can I place all rules for the moderator, signup and signin in their own directories, and do a rewrite rule in the root `.htaccess` file, that when it detects a url with `mod`, like `/mod/all` will send that request to the `moderator` directory. That way the root .`htaccess` file will have only the last two rules for the front end user along with others like `no hot linking` ones.

Something like:

```
If (URL Starts with '/mod/') 
  then send it to the '/moderator/' folder where the RewriteRules there will apply)

If (URL Starts with '/signup/' 
  then send it to the '/acc/' folder where the RewriteRules there will apply)
and so on.
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/acc/ ...handles account login and creation
/display/ ... handles front end display
/moderator/ ...the sites administrator
```

**part of my .htaccess file**

```
# Mod RewriteRules, some 12 in all 
RewriteRule ^/?(mod)/(all|new|edit|redo|reject)/(push)/?$ /moderator/index.php?mode=$2&push=0 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(mod)/(all|new|edit|redo|reject)/?$ /moderator/index.php?mode=$2 [NC,L]

#signUp - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signup)/?$ /acc/signup/index.php?a=signUp [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(signup)/(process)/?$ /acc/signup/process/index.php [NC,L]

#signIn - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signin)/?$ /acc/signin/index.php?a=signIn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(signin)/(process)/?$ /acc/signin/process/index.php [NC,L]

#signOut - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signout)/?$ /acc/signout/index.php [NC,L]

# These are the only two that a front end user will use
# category/subCategory
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /display/index.php?t=$1&s=$2 [NC,L]

# category
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z-]+)/?$ /display/index.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you look at the above rules, the last two are the only ones that a user using the front end will use. However, the cannot be placed on top, because they'll end up catching anything first, because of the way they are.

Comment: Have you tested how much time it would save on a regular request if you deleted the rules for `mod` temporarily. I bet you that their is no significant difference and therefor not really worth your time.

Comment: There's a lot more than this. Besides, it keeps things clean and easy to maintain. There are rules to create content etc.

Comment: Probably I missed something. What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: @anubhava There's no problem with my current approach, it's just that I don't want to go matching all the rules that are unnecessary. So I'd like to keep all the mod rules in an `.htaccess` file in the directory `moderator`, and then have a condition/rewrite rule in the root `.htaccess` file that sends all urls with `mod` in them to the directory `moderator`. In all, it's how to do the condition/rule that takes a url with `mod` and sends it to the folder `moderator` that I'm stuck with.

Comment: But `/mod/` or `/signup/` or `/signin/` URIs will need to be handled at least one rule in root .htaccess (may be to forward it to `/moderator/`) will that simplify things for you?

Comment: @anubhava  Yes, thats right. One rule in the root htaccess that will forward it to the moderator folder is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Have root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# forward mod|signup|signin|signout to /moderator/
RewriteRule ^(mod|signup|signin|signout)(/.*)?$ /moderator%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

# These are the only two that a front end user will use
# category/subCategory
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /display/index.php?t=$1&s=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# category
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z-]+)/?$ /display/index.php?t=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then have `/moderator/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /moderator/

RewriteRule ^/?(mod)/(all|new|edit|redo|reject)/(push)/?$ index.php?mode=$2&push=0 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(mod)/(all|new|edit|redo|reject)/?$ index.php?mode=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#signUp - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signup)/?$ /acc/signup/index.php?a=signUp [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(signup)/(process)/?$ /acc/signup/process/index.php [NC,L,QSA]

#signIn - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signin)/?$ /acc/signin/index.php?a=signIn [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(signin)/(process)/?$ /acc/signin/process/index.php [NC,L,QSA]

#signOut - Again, not always needed
RewriteRule ^/?(signout)/?$ /acc/signout/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You rules work excellent. However, there's one tiny thing that I cannot get past from all this time. This rule `RewriteRule ^(signin)(/.*)?$ /acc%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` works fine if the URL has a trailing slash Eg: `http://www.example.com/signin/` but not without the slash. Without the trailing `/` the URL in the address bar turns to `http://www.example.com/acc/signin` I tried adjusting the rule in several ways, but nothing works right. It needs to work with or without the trailing `/`

Comment: I believe `signin` is not a real folder right? Is `/acc/signin` a folder?

Comment: Yes, it is a real folder.

Comment: So I think you need to tell a bit more about directory structures. What are all the sub directories under `DocumentRoot`

Comment: Are all of these `mod,signup,signin,signout` sub directories under `DocumentRoot`?